# Invalid head of packet (0x38) while booting ESP8266-01S through Arduino Uno

Tags: esp8266, arduino-uno, arduino-esp8266

I have spent my complete day, trying to solve failures, that occurred during working with ESP8266-01S Module. Every time it gives me different error messages and every time I fix one - another pops out. This time it`s:

*A fatal esptool.py error occurred: Invalid head of packet (0x38)*

The scheme and settings I use are shown in articles below:

- https://www.kolkataonweb.com/code-bank/arduino/esp-01-flashing-errors/
- https://www.donskytech.com/program-esp8266-esp-01-with-arduino/?utm_content=cmp-true

The code I tried to upload is *Blink.ino*

I have tried changin the settings, proved wiring and placed it in different ways.

Comment: did you upload a sketch without Serial.begin into the Uno?

Comment: What do you mean? I have just used the basic Blinc.ino example.